# MinGW where is "cat" and "ls"? Simple commands are missing

Tags: windows, mingw

Performed a fresh install of mingw. here's exactly what i did:

```
 mingw-get-setup.exe
```

installed to i:\mingw

using the GUI selected the following packages:

```
mingw-developer-toolkit
mingw-gcc-g++
msys-base
```

setup fstab:

```
i:
cd \mingw\msys\1.0\etc
copy fstab.sample fstab
```

change c:/mingw to i:\mingw
comment out perl

add to PATH:

```
i:\mingw\bin;i:\mingw\msys\1.0\bin
```

various things work, but there's no "cat" nor "ls". Looking inside i:\mingw these files just aren't there.

tried the shell:

```
i:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat
```

eg `which gcc` gives:

```
$ which gcc
/bin/which: line 47: ls: command not found
/bin/which: line 47: ls: command not found
/mingw/bin/gcc
```

any idea what package is missing. 
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had to `set path=%path%;c:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\`

Answer (score 0):

turned out the file, `coreutils-5.97-3-msys-1.0.13-bin.tar.lzma` was corrupt.

Looks like the mingw-get does not check for errors when it downloads. :-(